# Latic Hypercube Sampling from categorical distributions in Python

Tags: python, sampling

I have 3 lists including categorical values. I want to generate an array of 10 samples of combinations of values of three lists using hypercube sampling. I don't want full factorial combinations but random selection of combinations using LHS.
Assume these are my lists:

```
list-1 = [a,b,c,d,e]
List-2 = [2001, 2002,2003, 2004]
List-3 = [red, green, blue, yellow]
```

I want to generate an array like this:

```
 array([[a, 2001, red  ],
           [a, 2001,green ],
           [a, 2001, blue],
           [a, 2001, yellow],
           [b, 2001, red],...........])
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across something similar and found your post while looking for a solution.
I'm not a expert in python, but [scipy.stats.qmc.LatinHypercube.integers](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.stats.qmc.LatinHypercube.integers.html) might be of help, by assigning each categorical level a integer number, LHS can be done and reflect back to the original categorical values.

```
from scipy.stats import qmc
sampler = qmc.LatinHypercube(d=2)
sample = sampler.integers(l_bounds=[1,1], u_bounds=[10,7], n=12)
x1 = np.split(sample, 2, axis=1)[0]
x2 = np.split(sample, 2, axis=1)[1]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).